# TextView with Database

Tags: android, sql

I'd like to put some data in a TextView. My Code so far:

```
    myDataBase = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();  
    Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(KLASSEN_SELECT_RAW, null); 
    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    SimpleCursorAdapter sca =
    new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.barinfo_layout, cursor, new String[] 
                             {"name"}, new int[] {R.id.barinfo_barinfo});

    barinfo.setText((CharSequence) sca);
```

Eclipse doesn't show errors but the programm chrashes when I execute it.
What do I have to change?

Comment: What's the adb logcat output?